# "Как собак нерезанНых" — сколько Н?

Tags: орфография

Что-то вдруг завис на этом фразеологизма: а сколько должно быть Н в слове "нерезан(н)ых"? С удвоенной Н Ворд подчеркивает как ошибку, но тут ведь есть приставка. И я уже не помню, распространяется ли правило о суффиксах "ан" и "енн" на отглагольные прилагательные.
Спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Правило о суффиксах *ан,ян,ин, енн, онн* на отглагольные прилагательные не распространяется. Только на именные. Приставка НЕ тоже на количество НН не влияет. Отглагольное прилагательное не имеет других приставок, зависимых слов, суффиксов *ова, ева ирова.* Пишем одну Н.

Формулирую правило. Если отглагольное слово (полное прилагательное или причастие - сразу трудно бывает понять, что именно)  образовано от глагола, то анализируем его на 4 условия:

- наличие приставки, кроме НЕ
- совершенный вид
- суффиксы ова, ева, ирова
- наличие зависимого слова (кроме наречий степени, типа очень).
    Если выполняется хотя бы одно условие, пишу две НН. Есть исключения. Есть слово раненый, которое ведет себя особенно. Но спрашивали не все правило, а только о конкретном слове.

Подробнее [здесь](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=52#pp52)

Comment: Сформулируйте правило, а то у Вас сплошные отрицания : не распространяется, не влияет, не имеет. А что имеется конкретно, кроме утверждения " пишем одну Н"? (я-то ошибся, конечно)))

Comment: Хорошо. Дополню.

Comment: Ранен(н)ый не исключение. Просто это другая ступень правила. Оно может быть и прилагательным и причастием и существительным (субстантивированным прилагательным). И не всегда понятно, чем оно является в конкретном случае. 
А вообще говоря Лопатин (и Со) не зря предлагал устранить лакуны правил именно в этой части - и свести все ко вполне постижимым формальным признакам. Ибо ключевой пункт - наличие зависимых слов - частенько противоречит базовому подходу "глагольность или качественность признака".

Кстати, Вы не в курсе, источник этот с учетом предложений ОК сделан или нет?

Comment: 1. А я говорила, что раненый исключение?  2. Я правило не перечитывала, я  его знаю.3. Ссылку дала на Лопатина. 4. Источник обычно указываю. если отвечаю, предварительно поискав или уточнив ответ. Или если пишу только основное из правила, как в данном случае 5. Правило перечитала, ничего нового не нашла.

Comment: >Ссылку дала на Лопатина. 
  
Я и спрашиваю про Лопатина. Комуж как не ему пложы трудов своих в массы двигать?!  
Ладно, я сам посмотрю, как так правило про н/нн в причастиях подаётся.

Comment: >А я говорила, что раненый исключение? (и далее)
  
А я говорил, что Вы говорили? Ларf, ну что за футбол, в который Вы решили поиграть? Я не задевал Вас лично, могу даже извиниться, знать бы за что.

Comment: ДА, я согласна, что написание слов типа жареный и жаренный в масле можно было бы унифицировать.

Answer (score 0):

Нереза(н,нн)ых - от глагола "(не)резать" несов. вида;нет зав. слов; нет "ова/ева"; нет приставки (приставка "НЕ" не работает); следовательно, пишу нерезаных.

> Но можно следовать внутреннему убеждению)

Таково правило. Оно и убеждает писать грамотно.

Comment: Какие все-таки сложные аналитические операции надо произвести, навроде как день Пасхи вычислить на костяшках пальцев. Но можно следовать внутреннему убеждению)